# java, okhttp, I get these exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Buffer, without module not

Tags: java, gradle, module, okhttp

I use java 17 and okhttp-4.9.3. The call is:

```java
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
```

Running the program, i get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "ReadStationsThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Buffer
at okhttp3@4.9.3/okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion.create(ResponseBody.kt:248)
at okhttp3@4.9.3/okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion.create$default(ResponseBody.kt:247)
at okhttp3@4.9.3/okhttp3.internal.Util.\<clinit\>(Util.kt:65)
```

The program can be build without error. I use gradle with these dependencies:

```
implementation ':okhttp-4.9.3'
implementation ':okio-3.3.0'
implementation ':okio-jvm-3.3.0'
implementation ':kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21'
```

in the module-info.java is these:

```
requires okhttp3; 
requires okio; 
requires kotlin.stdlib;
```

running the program, calls the exception. When i remove the mdule-info.java file, also running the program without modules, it works without problems. Anny idea what the module-info misses?

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was this version combination:

- `okio-3.5.0`
- `okio-jvm-3.5.0`
- `okhttp-4.11.0`
- `kotlin-stdlib-1.6.20`

Comment: Thank you for this. I was missing the okio-jvm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it'll answer your question but found this [issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4184) in okhttp repository discussing that okio and related dependencies does not support Java 9 Platform Module System (aka JPMS).

Also see that [other issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6857) which is related to the first one.

Moreover, when you look at `okio-3.3.0.jar`'s `MANIFEST.MF` file, you'll find that there's no `Automatic-Module-Name` directive (which is `Automatic-Module-Name: okio` in `okio-jvm-3.3.0.jar`). Since the `Builder` class is located in the okio's jar, that would explain why it can't resolve it with current configuration.

Knowing that, is module support a *true* need in your project since it works without it ?

Comment: is module support a true need: yes, i added it to all progs.

Comment: Since `requires okio;` loads the `okio-jvm` declared module, I'm pretty sure the problem is that the `okio` library doesn't get his classes loaded since both shared the same `package`. Did you try upgrading to latest version of okhttp / okio / okio-jvm / kotlin-stdlib ?